# If cocoa app crashes where is stacktrace /crash log stored?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I am new to mac and cocoa development. When a cocoa app crashes there is a windows that asks the user to report crash log to apple. I want to write a customized reporting component. So I want to know if crash reports /log are automatically stored somewhere are these simple text files or core dumps ?

I am looking to support 10.5 to 10.8

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Crash logs can be found in a number of places.

In MacOS 10.8 (and I believe also 10.7) crash logs would be "`~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports`" or "`/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports`" (the first is for crashes for user apps and the second is for system-wide apps).

Now instead of "reinventing the wheel", you may want to consider third party alternatives that can generate and return crash reports to you.  [Wikipedia lists these](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crash_Reporter_%28OS_X%29):

- Unsanity developed an Input Manager called Smart Crash Reports, that
  patches Apple software to include a "submit to developer" button
  within Crash Reporter. Smart Crash Reports only works with Mac OS
  X 10.4 and 10.5.
- Uli Kusterer wrote [UKCrashReporter](http://www.zathras.de/angelweb/sourcecode.htm#UKCrashReporter), which can send the output of Apple's Crash Reporter to a developer the next time the
  application is started.
- [CMCrashReporter](http://cmcrashreporter.codingmammoth.com/) is a small opensource framework, which can send the crashlog to the developer (via HTTP POST) and let the user
  enter optional details.
- [ILCrashReporter-NG](http://code.google.com/p/ilcrashreporter-ng/), a fork of Infinite Loop's ILCrashReporter (which was for Mac OS X 10.2-10.5); current OS support unknown
- [plcrashreporter](http://code.google.com/p/plcrashreporter/) Plausible CrashReporter provides an in-process crash reporting
  framework for use on both the iPhone and Mac OS X
- [Google Breakpad](http://code.google.com/p/google-breakpad/), an open-source multi-platform crash reporting system